# How to properly install node on OSx?

Tags: node.js, macos, installation

tl;dr: how to install node properly, without all the $PATH errors and `command not found`?

**Let me illustrate my problem with the following story:**

I've been trying to install node "properly". I did the basic install, with it's installer, and found [this](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814) (tl;dr: do not sudo node).

Ok, let's remove node and reinstall it with nvm and all. Great. Now, my $PATH doesn't point properly. Let's search a way to fix the $PATH.

Fixed the $PATH after several tries and failures? Great. Let's test... `node -v` returns `4.5.0`... hmm, I'm sure it had a different version. Anyways, let's try installing gulp.

`npm install --global gulp-cli`, great, installed. Let's `npm gulp -v` to see if everything is alright —and it looks alright, as it returns `2.15.9`.

So, if I just `gulp` it should return an error (as I don't have a gulpfile or packages.json). When I `gulp` at the terminal, it returns: `zsh: command not found: gulp`

**So, i find out there's something not working properly again.**

After several tries, removes, uninstalls and reinstalls, I beg your help. How can I remove everything node related from my computer and which is the best way to install node? I just want to use gulp, eslint and sublime text 2 with it.

If I'm doing something terribly wrong or saying incorrect things... call me dumb but please do correct me.

OSx El Capitan 10.11.16
iTerm2 3.0.7 with Oh My Zsh
Sublime Text Stable Channel, Build 3114

Comment: I would recommend using [Homebew](http://brew.sh)

Comment: Ok, trying homebrew right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did try with Homebrew and it worked properly.